# How to check if a number is already dispalyed - game

Tags: c++

I have `vector< vector< set< int > > >` for the board where each square is a set and initially has all the possible numbers that can go in `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}`. Every time a square is set by a number being passed,;I need to go through all the elements of the box and delete that value from all the squares. I have the code here:

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


class Sudoku{
    private:
        int size;
        vector< vector< set< int > > > board;

    public:
        Sudoku(int sizeIn):
        size(sizeIn){}

        void setSodoku() { board = vector<vector<set<int>>>(size, vector<set<int>>(size, { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 })); } 

        void getSquare(int row, int col){
            for(auto i : board[row][col]) std::cout << i << '\n';
        }

        bool setSquare(int row, int col, int value){    
            int tempRow = row / size;
            int tempColumn = col / size;

        for (int rowC=(tempRow*size);rowC<=((tempRow*size)+(size-1));rowC++)
        {
            for (int columnC=(tempColumn*size);columnC<=((tempColumn*size)+(size-1));columnC++)
            {
                if(board[rowC][columnC].count(value)==1)
                {
                    board[rowC][columnC].erase(value);
                }

                if(board[rowC][columnC].empty())
                {
                    cout << "wait 2 " << endl;
                    return false;
                }

            }
        }

         return true;           
    }           
};

int main(){

    // | 2 | 3 |   |     | 9 | 1 | 5 |      |   |   |   |
    // |   |   |   |     | 2 |   |   |      | 5 | 4 |   |
    // | 6 |   | 7 |     |   |   |   |      |   |   |   |
Sudoku boardTest(9);
boardTest.setSodoku();
boardTest.setSquare(0,0,2);
boardTest.setSquare(0,1,3);
boardTest.setSquare(0,3,9);
boardTest.setSquare(0,4,1);
boardTest.setSquare(0,5,5);

boardTest.setSquare(1,3,2);
boardTest.setSquare(1,6,5);
boardTest.setSquare(1,7,4);

boardTest.setSquare(2,0,6);
boardTest.setSquare(2,2,7);

cout << "--------" << endl;
boardTest.getSquare(1,0);


    return 0;
}
```

When I try to print what elements are in the row 0 and column 1 it displays 8 which should actually be 1,4,5,8,9 as 2,3,6,7 are already in box 0 (first one).

I know I need to have it 9x9 but this is only for test purpose.

Comment: Not sure what the question is... But from my experience with similar posts I have to ask this: have you tried to debug your code in a debugger? What was the issue that you've identified while debugging?

Comment: @YePhIcK The thing is that the code compiles so it doesn't display anything when I try to back trace it.

Comment: It seems that getSquare looks at hte entire board since 4 and 8 are the numbers missing everywhere, In getSquare you use board[col][row], while in setSquare board[rowC][columnC] - is there an error in the order?

Comment: @PeterLeupold Thanks for the reply, I think you are right, I added 4 ( which I forgot to add as it is displayed in the drawing I have ). So, I added 4 and It displayed 8. I changed the order for getSquare and the problem is the same ( it displays 8 )

Comment: Unrelated: You are using `emplace`, so you should be able to replace your `setSodoku` function with something like `void setSodoku()
    {
        board = vector<vector<set<int>>>(size, vector<set<int>>(size,
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }));
    }
`

Comment: @PeterLeupold I edited the for loop, but I am still getting the same error. Not sure what is wrong, can u help me please ? I've been trying to solve it for 4 hours.

Comment: What @YePhIcK is likely suggesting is you step through the program in the debugger and keep an eye out for where your code does something you didn't expect.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks, I updated the code. It looks much better now.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks, I'm using gdb. I only know how to run and back trace it. Currently watching a YouTube video about it. I will see how I can use it to see each variable.

Comment: Time well spent. The debugger is an invaluable tool for every programmer. It is likely the best programming productivity tool you will ever find, so time invested in learning to use one now will save you unfathomable amounts of time later. That said, if you can use a front end to make GDB easier to use, do it.

Answer (score 1):

I got it sorted. The code had 2 bugs.

1) it should be square root of the size and not size.

2) it should have check if size of the set is not equal to 1 in this if statement  `if(board[rowC][columnC].count(value)==1)`